# How to access the file path separator for the current platform?

Tags: rust, filesystems, separator, os-agnostic

Are there any available option to get platform specific file separator in Rust?

There can be different platform specific separators:

```
let separator = "\\" // Could be this.
let separator2 = "/" // Could be this.
let separator3 = "//" // Could be this.
```

I am looking like something following:

```
let env_independent_seperator = env::separator()
```

Then it may be the usage can be follows:

```
let folder = "C\\Folder\\Path";
let env_independent_separator = env::separator() // Looking something like this
let file_name = "File.txt";
let full_path = folder+ env_independent_separator + file_name;
```

Are there any `File::separator()` in Rust?

Comment: You also might prefer to use `PathBuf` and/or `Path` for these kind of things. Especially `Path.join` or `PathBuf.push`

Comment: Note that you can use `/` as a separator on virtually every platform inlcuding Windows.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of using custom operations with separator one should use `Pathbuf` or `Path` for this problem.

- [`Path.join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join)
- [`Pathbuf.push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push)

In case of platform specific separator one should use [`std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR.html).

**UPDATE:**
As of Rust version 1.68
There is also [`std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR.html), which has the separator as a `const &str`

Comment: As of 1.68 there is also [`MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR_STR.html), which has the separator as a `const &str`